# "Golden rule to making money"

Tags: prepositions, british-english

> Virgin founder Richard Branson’s ‘golden rule’ to making money from investments revealed ([source](https://www.express.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/1268184/virgin-atlantic-news-richard-branson-investment-tip-shares-stock-market-ftse-spt))

This headline from a Daily Express piece grates. The preposition used after *rule* is usually "of" or "for". "A rule to something" sounds odd to my ear, although I understand the usage here might manifest the lax grammar of headlinese. Why is "to" used here? I wonder if this is a BrE usage.

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly "British" about the Express's preposition use as cited. I've no doubt that ***to*** is almost certainly far less common than  ***for*** in the exact context, but I think it's pedantic in the extreme to imply that either version is somehow "incorrect". There are *some* contexts where only one preposition is "acceptable", but this isn't one of those. In any case, I have to say that I'd *vastly* prefer ***to*** over ***of*** here.

Comment: Note from a Brit - even if I agreed with the Daily Express's far-right politics, which I don't, I'd have to admit that its standards of copy editing are very low, and errors like 'golden rule to' are not all that unusual. The newspaper is a very down market trashy tabloid.

Comment: I spent approximately two minutes on the Daily Express web site before I found this complete sentence: "After Harry launched the Travalyst initiative in Edinburgh earlier this year, and Harry asked to be introduced just by his first name."

Answer (score -1):

> Why is "to" used here?

The best answer is probably this comment: "The newspaper is a very down market trashy tabloid."  However, the cause-and-effect in this case should not be attributed merely to lax copy editing.

The tone of such a newspaper is *sensationalistic*.

The correct word "for" would be boring, and make the sentence ordinary.

Not sensational.

Also, it appears they would like to conjure this sort of phrase in the reader's mind: "Richard Branson’s guide **to** riches", where "to" fits better.